# The number of $f \circ f=f $

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinatorial-number-theory

Let $A=\{1,2,3...n\}$，How many functions satisfy the following conditions？

(1) $f \circ f=f $

(2) $f \circ f =I_A$

(3) $f \circ f\circ  f=I_A$

$\circ$ is composite.

The question is from a 'Discrete Mathematics' book, and the book gave the answer of the first two questions.

(1)  $n+1$

(2) $ C_n^2+1(\tbinom{n}{2}+1)$

But I think the answer of first is wrong.It should be $\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\tbinom{n}{k}k^{n-k}}$.

For the $f$ satisfied (1), The $f=\{<1,b_1>,<2,b_2>,...<n,b_n>\}$, and if $ b_n\neq n$, there is $<b_n,b_n>$ in $f$.

**EDIT**

*For the answer I gave, I think it's wrong now.Because I think it contains repeated parts.That is, it is bigger than the correct answer.*

**I want to konw my answer whether is correct,and get the answer or hint of the three questions**

**Any help would be greatly appreciated :-)**

**Thanks very much!**

Comment: Do you suppose you know where the $n+1$ is coming from? There are certain trivial functions that you should think of first, and then show that anything else can't satisfy the claim.

Comment: @Robert Wolfe I think it is wrong,and I don't know where the $n+1$ is coming from.

Comment: It suddenly dawned on me that my answer was also wrong.It repeated the count.

Comment: I don't think the second is right either.  You are trying to count the number of permutations of order $2$ (plus the identity).  That computation can be found, e.g., [here](https://sriasat.wordpress.com/2015/03/15/number-of-permutations-of-order-2/)

Comment: What text was this, by the way?

Comment: Perhaps there is some extra condition imposed on $f$ you may be missing, like surjectivity?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff There is only one surjective map satisfying (1).

Comment: I'm not saying that's the condition missing, I'm just saying the OP may be missing a part of the exercise.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the answer in the book is obviously wrong for $n = 1$ as there is only $1$ possible map to begin with.

Now for the actual solution, assume that $f$ satisfies (1). Set $B := f(A)$. By assumption we must have $f(x) = x$ for all $x \in B$. For $x \notin B$, there is no further restriction, it can be mapped to any point in $B$. There are $n \choose k$ ways to choose the set $B$ with $k$ elements. For the remaining $n-k$ elements there are $k$ possible choices each. We would therefore come up with
$$\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {n \choose k} k^{n-k}.$$

Comment: Number of $f$ satisfying $(2)$ is precisely the number of elements in $S_n$ of order $2$ and similarly the number of $f$ satisfying $(3)$ is precisely the number of elements in $S_n$ of order $3.$

Comment: So the answer to $(2)$ is $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\left [\frac n 2 \right]} \frac {n!} {2^{k+1} (k+1)! (n-2k-2)!}$ and similarly the answer to $(3)$ is $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\left [\frac n 3 \right ]} \frac {n!} {6^{k+1} (k+1)! (n-3k-3)!}.$

Comment: I think your answer  is wrong.Of course, this is also my initial answer.Because I think the answer is bigger than correct answer.It contains repeated parts

Comment: @梦里年华似烟花 I checked it by hand for $n = 3$. You could check larger $n$ with a computer, but I believe it should be correct.

Comment: @klaus But when $n$ is big ,I'm not able to know the correct answer.Even if I get the value of $\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {n \choose k} k^{n-k}$,how to check it?

Comment: @梦里年华似烟花 Write a computer program that checks all possibilities.

Comment: @Klaus Good idea.But there are $n!$ possibilities，it's so big!

Comment: $n^n$ actually, but a standard computer can check this at least up to $n = 10$ without issues. Of course, a computer program is not a proof, but it would give you some confidence that the argument above is correct (or prove me wrong otherwise).

Comment: For reference, the number of idempotent functions from $\{1,...,n\}\to \{1,...,n\}$ can be found here https://oeis.org/A000248

Answer (score 0):

First observe that the number of $f$'s satisfying $(ii)$ is precisely the number of elements in $S_n$ (the symmetric group with $n$-symbols) of order $2$ and similarly the number of $f$'s satisfying $(iii)$ is precisely the number of elements in $S_n$ of order $3.$

Now an element in $S_n$ of order $2$ is of the form $(a_{11}\ a_{12}) (a_{21}\ a_{22}) \cdots (a_{k1}\ a_{k2})$ for some $1 \leq k \leq \left [ \frac n 2 \right ]$ and similarly an element in $S_n$ of order $3$ is of the form $(a_{11}\ a_{12}\ a_{13}) (a_{21}\ a_{22}\ a_{23}) \cdots (a_{k1}\ a_{k2}\ a_{k3})$ for some $1 \leq k \leq \left [ \frac n 3 \right ].$

Now the number of elements in $S_n$ of the form $(a_{11}\ a_{12}) (a_{21}\ a_{22}) \cdots (a_{k1}\ a_{k2})$ for some $1 \leq k \leq \left [ \frac n 2 \right ]$  is $\frac {\binom n 2 \binom {n-2} {2} \cdots \binom {n-2n+2} {2}} {k!}$ which simplifies to $\frac {n!} {2^k k! (n-2k)!}$ and similarly the number of elements in $S_n$ of the form $(a_{11}\ a_{12}\ a_{13}) (a_{21}\ a_{22}\ a_{13}) \cdots (a_{k1}\ a_{k2}\ a_{k3})$ for some $1 \leq k \leq \left [ \frac n 3 \right ]$  is $\frac {\binom n 3 \binom {n-3} {3} \cdots \binom {n-3n+3} {3}} {k!}$ which simplifies to $\frac {n!} {6^k k! (n-3k)!}.$

So the answer to $(2)$ is given by

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\left [\frac n 2 \right]} \frac {n!} {2^k k! (n-2k)!}.$$

and similarly the answer to $(3)$ is given by

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\left [\frac n 3 \right]} \frac {n!} {6^k k! (n-3k)!}.$$

But sorry I don't know any further simplification of the above summations.

Comment: Could you please write more detail?For example, how the answer is coming from?

Comment: Well I will update it soon. After my college hours will be over today.

Comment: The form of your answer seems strange.  I think there should be a more concise form. Maybe it's a different way of counting.

Comment: I have actually counted the number of elements of order $2$ and $3$ in $S_n,$ the symmetric group with $n$ symbols. Those are precisely the number of $f$'s satisfying $(2)$ and $(3)$ respectively.

Comment: The elements of $S_n$ of order two are of the form $(a_{11}\ a_{12}) (a_{21}\ a_{22}) \cdots (a_{k1}\ a_{k2}),$ where $1 \leq k \leq \left [ \frac n 2 \right ].$ Similarly the elements of $S_n$ of order $3$ are of the form $(a_{11}\ a_{12}\ a_{13}) (a_{21}\ a_{22}\ a_{23}) \cdots (a_{k1}\ a_{k2}\ a_{k3}),$ where $1 \leq k \leq \left [ \frac n 3 \right ].$

Comment: Now how many elements are there in $S_n$ of the form$(a_{11}\ a_{12}) (a_{21}\ a_{22}) \cdots (a_{k1}\ a_{k2}),$ for some $1 \leq k \leq \left [ \frac n 2 \right ]$? Is it not $\frac  {{n \choose 2} {{n-2} \choose 2}{{n-4} \choose 2} \cdots {{n-2k+2} \choose 2}} {k!}$ which simplifies to $\frac {n!}  {2^k k! (n-2k)!}.$

Comment: Now how many elements are there in $S_n$ of the form$(a_{11}\ a_{12}\ a_{13}) (a_{21}\ a_{22}\ a_{23}) \cdots (a_{k1}\ a_{k2}\ a_{k3}),$ for some $1 \leq k \leq \left [ \frac n 3 \right ]$? Is it not $\frac  {{n \choose 3} {{n-3} \choose 3}{{n-6} \choose 3} \cdots {{n-3k+3} \choose 3}} {k!}$ which simplifies to $\frac {n!}  {6^k k! (n-3k)!}.$

Comment: That's how I have got the above two strange looking summations @梦里年华似烟花.

Comment: But sorry I don't know any further simplification to the above summations. If you are eager enough to know whether there are much simpler expressions to the above summations please ask it as a different question in this site. But please don't forget to share me the link then. It will also very helpful for me. Thank you very much.

Comment: Why do you edit your answer?@Dbchatto67

Comment: Which answer do you talk about?

Comment: Ok, when I add comment, you haven't edit your  this answer.@Dbchatto67